# $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim \mu} [f(X)]$ notation (Expectation with subscript random variable following particular distribution).

Tags: probability-theory, notation

When $X$ is a random variable what exactly does the notation $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim \mu} [f(X)]$ mean? Is it $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim \mu} [f(X)]=\int f(x)\mu(dx)$. Is it what we would also denote by $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ knowing that $X$ has probability distribution $\mu$?

Comment: Yes I think so.